# Check if file exist before print

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Can someone help me connect some code??

What I want is a code that does this: If a picture exist then print it, else don't print anything.
(This code is used to find the pichure)
and I need help to conect the if statment to the one in the other code

```
<?php
$pathToFileOnDisk = 'inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg';
if(file_exists($pathToFileOnDisk) && is_readable($pathToFileOnDisk)) {
<img  src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $name . '" width="100%" height="260" border="1" />
}
else {
// NO IMG
}
?>
```

AND

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php 
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
         $id = $row["id"];
         $name = $row["name"];
         $content = $row["content"];
         $date_added = strftime("%d %b, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
         $dynamicList .= '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
         <td>
         <div id="left">

                <img  src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $name . '" width="100%" height="260" border="1" />  <-- !!THIS IS WHAT I WANNA REPLACE!!
            </div> <!-- End Left-->
    </td>
    <div id="right">


      <td width="630px" valign="top"><h2><a id="overskrift" href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $name . '</a></h2>
      <p><b>
        Skrevet den ' . $date_added . '<br />
        ' . $content . '</b></p>
        </td>
        </div>
    </tr>
  </table><br />';
}
} else {
$dynamicList = "Ingen inlegg enda..";
}
mysql_close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
        </header>  <!-- End Header -->
        <div id="banner"></div>
        <div class="content test clearfix">


            <?php echo $dynamicList; ?>
            </div> <!-- End Content -->

        <footer>
            <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
        </footer> <!-- End Footer -->

    </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->
</body>
```

Comment: +1 for making me chuckle with your temporary website. Look forward to seeing it when it's finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use this:-

```
<?php
$filename = 'some_name';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "File exists";
} else {
    echo "File does not exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: I saw that code But I have no idea how to connect it to my code..
Does it exist if and if, else. Or somthing like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `file_exists()` and `is_readable()` functions.

The first will tell if the file exists, and the second will tell if you have permissions to read the file, before actually doing it. Similarly, there's also the `is_writable()` function, which tells you if you have permissions to write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

The [file_exists](http://www.php.net/file_exists) and [is_readable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) functions are perfect for this purpose.

For example:

```
<?php
    $pathToFileOnDisk = '/full/system/path/to/image.jpg';
    if(file_exists($pathToFileOnDisk) && is_readable($pathToFileOnDisk)) {
        // The file exists and can be read
    }
    else {
        // The file doesn't exist (or does exist, but PHP can't read it).
        // Perhaps output a placeholder image here.
    }
?>
```

Incidentally, I'd recommend a quick glance at all of the [filesystem functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php), as the time spent on this now will pay dividends in the future.

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way I can connect my code to this one?

Comment: @HenrikHilmerEngelshus You can simply use this (supplying the relevant path) when you output the IMG tag. (i.e.: Within the `<div id="left">` section.)

Comment: Can I have a if else inside a if else ?

Comment: Okey, I am just so lost! I have no idea how to connect the code to my code.. As I said, I don't know a lot of PHP..
I have some Idea how this can work, But I don't know how to do it the right way.. Can someone help me?

Comment: @HenrikHilmerEngelshus Yes, you can "nest" if-else constructs. Incidentally, you might want to read the [PHP tutorial](http://uk1.php.net/tutorial) as it'll bring you up to speed on the basics.